# Find for specific word in textbox and delete all lines what contains that word

Tags: c#

I need code what will check if word exist in `textBox1` and delete line if contain that word.

Word is `crosshair 1`

I created cod if `checkBox1.checked` write some text in `textBox1` now i need just that code to `serach` for word and delete line ... Thanks in advance !!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConfigMaker
{
    public partial class createnew : Form
    {
        public createnew()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Configuration files | *.cfg";
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "cfg";
        }

        private void bunifuCheckbox1_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bunifuCheckbox1.Checked)
            {
                textBox1.Text += "crosshair 1" + "\r\n";
            }
            else
            {


            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                File.WriteAllText(name, textBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var value = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
            label3.Text = value;
            textBox1.Text += "brightness " + value + "\r\n";
        }

        private void name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text += "name " + '\u0022' + name.Text + '\u0022' + "\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of `createnew` form.
Now i need to to next, when `bunifucheckbox1 unchecked` if `crosshair 1` exists delete `crosshair 1` from `textbox1.text`

If `trackbar1.value = 0`, if `brightness "value"` exists delete `brightness "value"` from `textbox1.text`

And if `textbox2.Text empty`, if `name "value"` exists delete `name "value"` from `textbox1.text`.

I tried to use this code

```
private void bunifuCheckbox1_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string crosshair = "crosshair 0";
            string crosshair1 = "crosshair 1";
            if (bunifuCheckbox1.Checked)
            {
                textBox1.Text += crosshair.Replace(crosshair, crosshair1)  + "\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text += crosshair + "\r\n";
            }
        }
```

But it still creating new line with replaced text...

Comment: The "word" appears to be *two* words. Do you mean string, not word? Then: What part do you have trouble with? Going through the text line by line (you must have the text as  string already, since you "wrote"  it to the text box)? Deleting lines? Setting a new text in the textbox should not be a problem, you have done that already. Please edit your question and add the missing information. It's best if you provide some code with it and indicate where your problem is, perhaps with some pseudo code!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Use [Environment.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netcore-3.1) for line endings to be portable.

Comment: Its not helpful .. For me..

Comment: Did you look at the [String class socumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netcore-3.1), specifically the [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1) method? I think if you replace with an empty string it  amounts to a deletion.

Comment: I tried that but not wotking how i want.. I am really sorry for wasting ur time but .. I dont know what to do ..

Comment: @StefanPisarov Environment.NewLine was a style remark. It won't help with your problem, and your program is of course Windows based, but it is *still* a good habit to be portable where possible. Among other things, it prevents mistakes like "\n\r".

Comment: Re "I tried that but not wotking how i want": Please be more specific. Tell us what you did, what you expected, and what you got instead. *Do that in the question!* Do that with all the other things you perhaps tried, as well. How can we help you if we must extract all information, instead of you providing it?

Comment: If user check checkbox1 write crosshair 1 in textbox.text when chechbox1 not checked  delete crosshair 1 if exists or to set crosshair 0 instead of crosshair 1 (ALL NEED TO HAPPEND IN ONE LINE O TEXTBOX.TEXT)
If trackbar value == 0 show brightness "0" in textbox.text (in new line) and if value of trackbar changed to replace brightness "0" (replace this 0) with value of trackbar

If textbox2.text empty in textbox1.text show name "You need to set ur name" or if textbox2.text have any text to replace "You need to set ur name" with that text from text box2.text .. 
I hope you understand me now

Comment: No, I don't. How did Replace() not work? And **please edit your question.** Do not provide information relevant to your question only in comments. One of the reasons, as you must have notices, is that comments do not permit full formatting.

Comment: I understand what you say but **you didn't answer my question: How did you try to use String.Replace(), and in which way did the result not meet your expectations?** That's a straightforward question. Please simply answer it: Show what you did, what you expected, and what you got instead. Simply repeating the text of your homework assignment does not help.

Comment: I edited question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see is that you are always *appending* to the original text. If your text box contains the string "crosshair 1\r\n", then the line

```
textBox1.Text += crosshair + "\r\n";
```

is equivalent to

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + crosshair + "\r\n";
```

which means

> obtain the text in the textbox, which is "crosshair 1\r\n", then append "crosshair\r\n" to it, and then set the resulting string ("crosshair 1\r\ncrosshair\r\n", i.e. two lines of text) as the new text of the text box.

It never *replaces* any part of the text in the text box, which seems to be what you want. If the text in the text box is always exactly just either "crosshair" or "crosshair 1" then you can also simply set the text to "crosshair 1", no need to fiddle with Replace().

So I think you must obtain the text from the text box first, change that and set it again (or simply set it directly):

```
string oldText = textBox1.Text; 
string newText = oldText.Replace(crosshair1, crosshair);
 // or simply newText = crosshair;
textBox1.Text = newtext;
```

Comment: This code delete other text from textbox1.text if replace is true..

Comment: I suppose it deletes only instances of crosshair1. From the documentation: "Returns a string that is equivalent to the current string except that all instances of oldValue are replaced with newValue." Note that *three* strings are involved: The current string for which the method is invoked; the pattern in it which should be replaced; and the string each pattern occurence will be replaced with.

Comment: Now when i check checkbox it show crosshair 1, when uncheck show crosshair 0 BUT when i check checkbox again it add corsshair 1 in same line...

Here is the example:
crosshair 0crosshair 0crosshair 0crosshair 0crosshair 0crosshair 1

Comment: I fixed that now i need to do that for trackbar1 .. i tried alone but not going good.. ?

Comment: "Not going good" is not enough of a problem description. I *think* you must do something very much along the lines of what I suggested here. If you have a *different* problem with manipulating strings (or manipulating GUI elements), ask a new question.

Comment: I not understand what you say now ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really give us much to go on e.g. multiline, single line TextBox.

At what point do you want the text to be tested, on entry, after entry, on the press of a button?

Have you even tried`String.Contains(…)`?

I suggest that you have a look at the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/search-strings) and choose an example that you understand and if you are still having problems then come back to us.

**edit**

If you're after changing text in the TextBox in as few lines as possible then you can just use `String.Replace`.

The `Text` property of `TextBox` is a string and `String.Replace` will only give you a changed string if it can perform the replacement that you ask of it.

So your code should be along the lines of:

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("crosshair 0", "crosshair 1");
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("crosshair 1", "crosshair 0");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I come here just when i can't understand any of tutorials/helps from other sites..

Comment: And, textbox1 is multiline, wrap false, vertical scrollbar, if you want i can edit post and enter whole code here.. ?

Comment: @StefanPisarov Yes, by all means edit your question so that we or somebody else can answer it. And yes, include code. If you can make a test program which is small enough to post here in its entirety, go ahead. If not, just post the relevant parts. (If in doubt, post all of it. That may be annoying but we can always ignore fluff. We cannot make up missing crucial parts.)

Comment: Also, which part of the documentation is it that you do not understand? If it is the string handling, please write a minimal console test program withoout all the GUI stuff and event handling, and show us where you struggle to apply the documentation info about how you split a string at newlines, or how find out whether a string contains a substring.

Comment: I edited post if its not helpfull, say me what to add or explain you ..